# Sets $Q$ such that outer measure $\mu^*$ equals inner measure $\mu_*$ form an $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$. For all $Q \subseteq \Omega$, let: $\mu^*(Q) = \inf \{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n): \forall n, A_n \in \mathcal{A} $ and $Q \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n \}$ and $\mu_*(Q) = \sup \{\mu(A): A \subset Q, A \in \mathcal{A} \}$.

Let $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ be the collection of all sets $Q \subseteq \Omega$ such that $\mu_*(Q) = \mu^*(Q)$.

I want to show that $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but I'm having trouble proving that $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is closed under taking countable unions. I can show $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$  is a Dynkin system, but I couldn't prove it was closed under taking intersections.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out this problem?